# React-Redux Drop HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I am building a React-Redux application that I have a shows a cancel button while a certain `HTTP` request in in progress. If the request executes successfully, the UI shows the results and if the user presses the cancel button, the UI shows something different.

Right now I am using the following function to kick off my request and update my Redux store once the request is finished.

```
export function doFetch(url) {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(url)
            .then((json) => dispatch({type: types.MY_SUCCESS_ACTION}, json))
            .catch((error) => dispatch({type: types.MY_FAILURE_ACTION, error}));
    }
}
```

Now the above code doesn't handle the case in which the use clicks the cancel button. Now ES7 is doing some work with [cancelable promises](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancelable-promises) which could fit my use case because then I would have a reference to my request promise which I could then cancel if the user hits the cancel button.

How would I do this in the meantime though. I need some way so that if the user hits the cancel button, I can dispatch an action which will drop the current `HTTP` request.

**Solution**

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';
Bluebird.config({
    cancellation: true
});
fetch.promise = Bluebird;
let curReqPromises = [];    

function doFetch(url) {
        return dispatch => {
            curReqPromises.push(bluebirdRequest(url)
                .then((json) => dispatch({type: types.MY_SUCCESS_ACTION}, json))
                .catch((error) => dispatch({type: types.MY_FAILURE_ACTION, error}));
        }
    }

    function bluebirdRequest(url) {
        return new Bluebird((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
            makeFetch(url)
                .then((json) => resolve(json))
                .catch((error) => reject(json));

            onCancel(() => {
                console.log('I was cancelled');
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to make promises cancellable.

1. Use [rxjs](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3030-canceling-rxjs-observables-with-ngondestroy-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm)
2. Use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html)

If you're not interested in doing either one of them then you care for the cancellation manually by creating a cancellation action and then ignoring the result of that fetch when the state is `cancelled`. Once the promise resolves you can reset the state to `notCancelled` but avoid state mutation from the fetch. It's messy and that is one of the selling points for rxjs or bluebird, both of which have cancellation built in.

Comment: I ended up using Bluebird. See me edit for my solution.